# Golang type assertion with pointers

Tags: pointers, go, struct, types, interface

I've been working in an interface to use as a hierarchical tree. The idea is to aloud the concrete implementations to call `.Children()`, `.Father()` and a function to auto populate the hierarchy based on a slice of `{id, FatherId}` schema.

I only need three different implementations of this interface, maybe it's more convenient to do the whole thing for each struct but I'm new to Go and decided to use this example to understand interfaces.

I've come to an interface that looks something like this:

```
type Node interface{
    Equals(nodo *Node) bool
    AddChild(child *Node)
    SetFather(father *Node)

    Children() []Node
    Father() *Node
}
```

So the idea is call a `Populate` function:

```
func Populate(plainNodes []Node, HierarchichalNodes *[]Node) {}
```

Plain nodes would be items defining the id of his father:

```
{id: "Animal", father: ""}
{id: "Plant", father: ""}
{id: "Mammals", father: "Animal"}
```

Hierarchical nodes would be the result:

```
Animal
|__Mammals

Plant
```

The problem I'm getting is when I try to implement the interface in a concrete struct, this case `"Category"`.

```
type Category struct{
    children []Category
    father Category
}

func (c Category) SetFather(node *Node) {
    v, ok = node.(*Category)
    c.father = v
}
```

Notice that in `Category` I want to work with `Category` father and children, not with interface `Node`.

I can't do the conversion, I get :

```
invalid type assertion: nodo.(*Category) (non-interface type *Node on left)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you shuoldn't pass interfaces as pointers.  a pointer to `*Category` is a  `Node`, not a pointer to `Node`.

Answer (score 7):

Your parameter is `node *Node`, it is of type `*Node`. `Node` is an interface type, but `*Node` is not: it is a pointer to interface.

Don't use pointer to interface, it is very rarely needed. Instead change it to `node Node`. Also change all your other `*Node` pointers to just `Node`.

Also if `Category.SetFather()` method intends to change the `Category` value identified as the receiver, it must be a pointer else you'd only end up changing a copy which will be discarded after `SetFather()` returns. So use a receiver like `c *Category`.

Going further, if the `node` argument contains a `*Category` wrapped in an interface, you can't directly assign it to `Category.father` as that is a non-pointer type `Category`. You need a pointer indirection, e.g. `c.father = *v`; or change the type of the `father` field to be a pointer: `father *Category`.

Corrected `SetFather()` method could look like this:

```
func (c *Category) SetFather(node Node) {
    if v, ok := node.(*Category); ok {
        c.father = *v
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I make SetFather a method of the (pointer?) interface?

Comment: @Marcos When you list the `SetFather()` method "under" `Node`, then it will be a method of the `Node` interface. When you declare a `func (c *Category) SetFather(node Node)` method, then this `SetFather()` becomes a method of the type `*Category` (the receiver). So if you do the same with all other methods of `Node`, then the type `*Categroy` will implement `Node` and so a value of type `*Category` can be assigned to a variable of type `Node`.

Comment: Pointers to interfaces are used quite often. The http-package of Go wouldn't work without them.

Comment: Just don't write node *Node in the function header (but keep the pointers elsewhere if you want to work with pointers).

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
(*nodo).(Category)
```

De-reference first, assert afterwards.